# Ignoring change to a file which is part of a git repository

Tags: git

I had to make a local modification of a file which is part of my git repo, but I don't to commit that file, or lose my modification. I don't want to have to git add -p every time either.
I added the file to my gitignore but this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [the path to your file]
```

you can reverse the operation at any point by calling

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [the path to your file]
```